# Which sin is worse homosexuality or murder

Tags: sin, homosexuality

Which sin is greater in the eyes if allah homosexuality or murder

Comment: Typically questions is X better/worse than Y are opinion-based (off-topic) unless one could focus on a reference for the comparision!

Answer (score 3):

Islam doesn't give a "sin ranking", so it might not be straightforward to say one is worse than the other.  To get a better mental picture, it's possible to compare the evidence for murder (major sin #2) with the evidence for sodomy (major sin #11) in al-Dhahabi's *Major Sins* ([PDF](http://www.islamtomorrow.com/books/major_sins/majorSins.pdf)).

It's natural to believe that murder is a worse sin than sodomy.  There's some Islamic reasons too, such as:

1. The Qur'an strongly emphasizes the effect of murder:

   > ... whoever kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the land - **it is as if he had slain mankind entirely** ...
   >   <sub>[Qur'an 5:32](https://quran.com/5/32)</sub>
   >
   > But whoever kills a believer intentionally - **his recompense is Hell, wherein he will abide eternally**, and Allah has become angry with him and has cursed him and has prepared for him a great punishment.
   >   <sub>[Qur'an 4:93](https://quran.com/4/93)</sub>

   While the Qur'an also emphasizes the sin of the people of Prophet Lut, it's not to the same extent.
2. In [Sahih al-Bukhari 2766](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/55/29), the Prophet describes the *seven great destructive sins*, including to

   > ... kill the life which Allah has forbidden except for a just cause.

   However, this hadith doesn't mention sodomy.

The worldly punishment for the two have comparable consequences.  Under [qisas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qisas) the punishment for murder is death, although this can be forgiven ([Qur'an 2:178](http://quran.com/2:178); [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/urn/41800)).  For sodomy, there's no fixed punishment ([Darul Ifta](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulifta-deoband/27744)), but is usually considered to be death in some way ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/38622), [Darul Ifta](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulifta-deoband/27744)).  Both of these punishments have technicalities (such as witnesses), and require a [qadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qadi) (Islamic judge).